# Missing characters while reading input with threads

Tags: multithreading, perl, file, stdin

Let's say we have a script which open a file, then read it line by line and print the line to the terminal. We have a sigle thread  and a multithread version.

**The problem is than the resulting output of both scripts is almost the same, but not exactly**. In the multithread versions there are about ten lines which missed the first 2 chars. I mean, if the real line is something line "Stackoverflow rocks", I obtain "ackoverflow rocks".

I think that this is related to some race condition since if I adjust the parameters to create a lot of little workers, I get more faults than If I use less and bigger workers.

The single thread is like this:

```
$file = "some/file.txt";
open (INPUT, $file) or die "Error: $!\n";

while ($line = <STDIN>) {
    print $line;
}
```

The multithread version make's use of the thread queue and this implementation is based on the [@ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) approach:

```
use threads            qw( async );
use Thread::Queue 3.01 qw( );

use constant NUM_WORKERS    => 4;
use constant WORK_UNIT_SIZE => 100000;

sub worker {
    my ($job) = @_;
    for (@$job) {
        print $_;
    }
}

my $q = Thread::Queue->new();


async { while (defined( my $job = $q->dequeue() )) { worker($job); } }
    for 1..NUM_WORKERS;

my $done = 0;    

while (!$done) {
    my @lines;

    while (@lines < WORK_UNIT_SIZE) {
        my $line = <>;
        if (!defined($line)) {
            $done = 1;
            last;
        }

    push @lines, $line;
}

$q->enqueue(\@lines) if @lines;
}

$q->end();
$_->join for threads->list;
```

Comment: The prints from your threads hit the target without any synchronization and sometimes overlap.  You can't (reliably) print to the same place from multiple threads/processes. Store results for each thread (in an array, say) and print from the parent, or write from each thread to a separate file, which are then joined.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Intensifying my research, I found Thread::Semaphore library. I don't know how reliable this is, but it seems to be working. Do you know any caveat of using this @zdim ?

Comment: For all I know it's a standard tool and I don't know of any specific caveats. (In general, just respect the normal warning to use Perl's interpreter threads suitably -- so to bear in mind that they aren't exactly lightweight. Using `Thread::Queue` supports that but doesn't do it all for us.)  I'd say that the question is about what you do in your application. The prints you aksed about are clearly placeholders for real work. What kind of work? How much communication does it need? Etc.  That would determine whether or not you need semaphores (or what else you may or not need).

Comment: I'm reading the input lines and filter some words from them (simplifying the problem here). Then I should write the result lines into a file, in order to the next process can read it and make new work with them. @zdim

Comment: And it doesn't matter that the output is no longer in order?

Comment: @PerlDuck No, it doesn't matter, in fact, they are unsorted

Comment: @IvánRodríguezTorres  I see. Then you can either have each thread write to its own file, which then need be merged -- or (better, I'd say) as [PelrDuck says](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42517799/4653379) (in a comment) push results to a queue which is printed by a separate thread.  You'll have serial writing but I don't see a way to avoid that.  (If you turn off buffering and start locking threads it's going to slow down _a lot_.)  Also, you can set the writing to go along with processing, as soon as messages are on their queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried your program and got similar (wrong) results. Instead of `Thread::Semaphore` I used `lock` from [`threads::shared`](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads/shared.html) around the `print` as it's simpler to use than T::S, i.e.:

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;
...
my $mtx : shared;

sub worker
{
    my ($job) = @_;
    for (@$job) {
        lock($mtx); # (b)locks
        print $_;
                    # autom. unlocked here
    }
}
...
```

The global variable `$mtx` serves as a mutex. Its value doesn't matter, even `undef` (like here) is ok.
The call to `lock` blocks and returns only if no other threads currently holds the lock on that variable.
It automatically unlocks (and thus makes `lock` return) when it goes out of scope. In this sample that happens
after every single iteration of the `for` loop; there's no need for an extra `{…}` block.

Now we have syncronized the `print` calls…

**But** this didn't work either, because `print` does buffered I/O (well, only O). So I forced unbuffered output:

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;
...
my $mtx : shared;
$| = 1;  # force unbuffered output

sub worker
{
    # as above
}
...
```

and then it worked. To my surprise I could then remove the `lock` and it still worked. Perhaps by accident. Note that your script will run significantly slower without buffering.

My conclusion is: you're [suffering from buffering](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html).